# Transposing a text file in Haskell

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

I was doing the exercises in here http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html . My solution to the problem where I need to transpose a text file seems to take a lot of CPU time. How can I improve below algorithm, if I could, to make it less CPU hungry.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Char(isAlpha)
interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
  input <- readFile inputFile
  writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
          args <- getArgs
          case args of
            [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
            _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

        -- replace "id" with the name of our function below
        myFunction = transpose

transpose :: String -> String
transpose input = tpose (lines input)

tpose [] = []
tpose xs = concat (map (take 1) xs) ++ "\n" ++ tpose (map (drop 1) xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Skip up to chapter 8, which talks about how inefficient the String datatype is, and proposes using ByteString instead.  There's also Data.Text, if your file is unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The `Data.List` module contains some useful functions, such as `transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`. There's also `lines` and `unlines` in the `Prelude`, which convert between a `String` and a `[String]` (by breaking on newlines).

So basically, you probably want something like

```
main = do
  [input,output] <- getArgs
  interactWith (unlines . transpose . lines) input output
```